# Add a new collection in firebase when the user create account using uid of user in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reactjs.net

I make to to do list website but I want to create for each new user who register a new collection. when it created must also create automatically a new doucment in firebase for it and then write the data(to do list) in this docu. (I am using firebase cloud)

here a new structure which i wish:
[image]

```
const handleSignUp = (e) => { // singup function in Component Signup.jsx 
e.preventDefault();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then(() => {
    // Signed up
    navigate("/");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert.message("error");
    // ..
  }); };


 // create todo in Main.jsx
  const createTodo = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e); // no reload for the page
    if (input === "") {
      alert("pleas enter a valid statment");
      return;
    } else {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "todo"), {
        text: input,
        completed: false,
      });
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    }
    setInput("");
  };
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a document in users collection after creating user? Have you tried `setDoc()` right before `navigate("/");` just like `addDoc()`?

Comment: i want to add new collection for new user. In document should have 2 values, first data like "i have to go to school", second boolean value which refere if the tasks completed or not.

Comment: Can you please create an example in Firestore console and share a screenshot of expected output?

Comment: i have edited my post with new photo. see it please .

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. It will be better if there is only one collection "users" and then each user has a _document_ with their UID in it. You can use a sub-collection to store the TODOs. Is that possible for you to restructure? I'll post an answer if the works for you?

Comment: yes it should work also, important for me, that every user has own document which created by signing up with his own data. and I can easily write into this data, read or delete etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you needs for this is:

```
Users (collection)
  $uid (documents)
    Todos (collection)
      $todoId (documents)
```

After the user is signed in, you can then add a Todo to their collection with:

```
const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
const todos = collection(db, "Users", uid, "Todos");
const docRef = await addDoc(todos, {
  text: input,
  completed: false,
});
```

Comment: thanks but the first block where should be written? and should I import something ?

Comment: The first snippet in my answer is not code, but a schematic depiction of the data structure. The second snippet is the code that needs to go wherever you want to write a TODO for that specific user, so the same place you currently do `await addDoc(collection(db, "todo"), {...`.